# Where can I find the Gotham HTF font for download or purchase?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

Where can I find the Gotham HTF font for download or purchase?

I searched on Google but could not figure out where to download this or whether it is even a free font versus paid.

Comment: The third result that I receive on Google when searching "Gotham HTF" is [this](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/gotham-htf). I was unable to find any information about how to download or purchase the font on that page. Please include the link to the third result that you get.

Comment: If you know that results may re-order per user then why even mention "It's discoverable on the third result by Googling" in your original response. If you can point me in the right direction to answer my question please help me out, if not there is no need to answer and be condescending about it.

Comment: Please [edit] additional information into your question or post a [self-answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know the Gotham typeface had a Gotham HTF version until your question popped up, which led me to this [question](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/642514/) because I was curious what the difference was between them both! I suppose they're of the same typeface but there were just some renaming/pirating issues.

If you're fine with just "Gotham", you can purchase a license of it at Hoefler & Co's official website, [here](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/). Or, as one of the users who posted in that forum question I mentioned above (scroll to the very bottom of the page), you can directly contact Hoefler & Co directly for the proper font and metrics.

Sorry I couldn't find a direct link for Gotham HTF but best of luck!

Comment: according to your linked question there isn't (or there shouldn't be) a link to a legal version of the HTF font. Also better to include the essential parts of what's behind that link in your answer. This way if the link breaks your answer won't lose part of the context.

Answer (score 0):

Gotham HTF simply means an old version of the Gotham typeface. When Tobias Frere-Jones and Jesse Ragan designed Gotham it was originally published by Hoefler Type Foundry, so "HTF" in the digital font files. The rights are now [owned by Monotype](https://qz.com/2068310/what-monotypes-purchase-of-hoeflerco-means-to-font-designers) who sell it from their storefronts [here](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/gotham-font-hoefler-and-co) and [here](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview). Any other download site would probably be pirating old files.